# Shortening JQuery animation code

Tags: jquery, animation

I'm new to developing JQuery code and i need some help shortening the following:

```
    $(".colorblue").mouseup(function(){
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.1, "swing" );  
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.1, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("body").removeClass("blank , green , orange , yellow").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("blue");
        next();
    });
});

$(".colorgreen").mouseup(function(){
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ); 
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("body").removeClass("blank , blue , orange , yellow").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("green");
        next();
    });
});

$(".colororange").mouseup(function(){
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ); 
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("body").removeClass("blank , blue , green , yellow").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("orange");
        next();
    });
});

$(".coloryellow").mouseup(function(){
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ); 
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("body").removeClass("blank , blue , orange , green").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("yellow");
        next();
    });
});

$(".colorblank").mouseup(function(){
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ); 
    $("#phone").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("body").removeClass("yellow , blue , orange , green").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("blank");
        next();
    });
});

// Menu changer 
$(".screenblue").mouseup(function(){
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.1, "swing" );   
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.1, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("menublank , menugreen , menuorange , menuyellow").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("menublue");
        next();
    });
});

$(".screengreen").mouseup(function(){
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" );  
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("menublank , menublue , menuorange , menuyellow").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("menugreen");
        next();
    });
});

$(".screenorange").mouseup(function(){
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" );  
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("menublank , menublue , menugreen , menuyellow").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("menuorange");
        next();
    });
});

$(".screenyellow").mouseup(function(){
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" );  
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("menublank , menublue , menuorange , menugreen").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("menuyellow");
        next();
    });
});

$(".screenblank").mouseup(function(){
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" );  
    $("#menu").fadeTo('fast', 0.01, "swing" ).delay(50).queue(function(next){
            $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
                next();
    });
    $("#wrapper").removeClass("menuyellow , menublue , menuorange , menugreen").delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass("menublank");
        next();
    });
});
```

I have heard using so many $ is not a good way to write JQuery code - it just controls some in browser animations.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

here is the html:

Sure, here is the html:

```
        <div id="phone"><div id="menu"></div></div><!--phone-->
        <div id="centercontainer">
            <br class="break" />
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="colorchanger" class="device">
                <h3>Device</h3>
                <a class="colorbox colorblue" href="#" title="Blue "></a>
                <a class="colorbox colorgreen" href="#" title="Green "></a>
                <a class="colorbox colororange" href="#" title="Orange "></a>
                <a class="colorbox coloryellow" href="#" title="Yellow "></a>
                <a class="colorbox colorblank reset" href="#" title="Blank "></a>
            </div>
            <div id="colorchanger" class="screen">
                <h3>Screen</h3>
                <a class="colorbox screenblue" href="#" title="Blue "></a>
                <a class="colorbox screengreen" href="#" title="Green "></a>
                <a class="colorbox screenorange" href="#" title="Orange "></a>
                <a class="colorbox screenyellow" href="#" title="Yellow "></a>
                <a class="colorbox screenblank reset" href="#" title="Blank "></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: *I have heard using so many $ is not a good way to write JQuery code*: Not necessarily. It's more concerning that you are repeating the same piece of code over and over again. Could you please provide an example of the relevant part of the HTML?

Comment: You could start by changing all the $("#menu") and $("#phone") into a variable instead of using a jquery selector each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it much shorter

```
var colors = new Array('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'yellow', 'blank');

$(".colorblue, .colorgreen, .colororange, .coloryellow .colorblank")
 .mouseup(function(){
    var $phone = $("#phone"), $this = $(this), $body = $("body"), idx, i;

    $phone.fadeTo('fast', 0.1, "swing");
    $phone.fadeTo('fast', 0.1, "swing").delay(50).queue(function(next){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing");
        next();
    });

    for(i = 0; i < colors.length; i ++) {
        if($this.hasClass('color' + colors[i])) 
            idx = i;
        else $body.removeClass(colors[i]);
    }

    $body.delay(400).queue(function(next) {
        $(this).addClass(colors[idx]);
        next();
    });
});

$(".screenblue, .screengreen, .screenorange, .screenyellow, .screenblank")
 .mouseup(function(){
    var $menu = $("#menu"), $this = $(this), $wrapper = $("#wrapper"), idx, i;
    $menu.fadeTo('fast', 0.1, "swing");   
    $menu.fadeTo('fast', 0.1, "swing").delay(50).queue(function(next){
        $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1, "swing" );
        next();
    });

    for(i = 0; i < colors.length; i ++) {
        if($this.hasClass('screen' + colors[i]))
            idx = i;
        else $wrapper.removeClass('menu' + colors[i]);
    }

    $wrapper.delay(400).queue(function(next){
        $(this).addClass('menu' + colors[idx]);
        next();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, as i put together the original code i can see what's going on, if you have a second could you explain the usage of idx here ?

Comment: `idx` indicates what color the screen or the body was. Since you bind mouseup event to all of those classes, you cannot just find out which class makes the event occurred. So, within the `for` statement `idx` rememebers the color class that it already has and makes you can add the class later.

Comment: @ChristopherCamplin and don't forget to check this answer if it really helps you :)

Comment: Just to let anyone using this code know, there is a missing comma on this line: $(".colorblue, .colorgreen, .colororange, .coloryellow .colorblank")
Thanks again.